# PHP: Server check if user is logged in or out

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm wanting to be able to tell if a user is logged in or not from the server end.  I currently have it set up where each user record in my database has an attribute 'loggedin' (boolean). If my user goes through the login process then he/she's 'loggedin' is set to '1'(true). If the user goes through the logout page I set it to '0'(false).  My problem is what if they don't go through the logout page but instead their cookie times out?

In hopes of helping anyone better understand what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm just trying to make a feature that will show on user's pages how long it has been since they were last logged in. I have it currently calculating but it shows either "user is online" or "online 4 minutes ago" depending on the 'loggedin' value in the database described earlier. So, if I visit a friends page then it will tell me how long ago it's been since they've been on.

** Just thought maybe store in the database another attribute that stores the timeout time of the cookie after login, so I could check for the 'loggedin' value and their timeout value to determine which information to display. This doesn't seem to be a very good way of doing it but i don't know.

If you have a better way of doing this than the method I've described above please clue me in :)

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Answer provided by Alexander Ivanov: if($_SESSION['logged'] == 1;) mysql_query('UPDATE users SET last_seen=NOW() WHERE id='. $user_id);  I've put a similar version of this in my code that authenticates the user. So everytime I auth the user it updates the time they were "last seen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use session variables:

```
$_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
```

You can use them throughout your script and their values will be kept between reloads.

Comment: The thing is the problem still persists is the session is not unset.

Comment: The session is automatically unset after 15 minutes after the user loses connection with the webpage (closes it).

Comment: if the session automatically times out after 15 minutes this would probably work. How do i check from the server side for a specific user's session though? Is there a way to search for a $_SESSION by user id?

Comment: Forgot to tell you that you need to use `session_start()` in the beginning of your script for sessions to work. Every time a user logs in you set `$_SESSION['logged'] = 1;` - the session variable is set only for this user so you don't have to worry for conflicts. But if you want to display this info to all users you should probably save the last action time of your user to the DB. `if($_SESSION['logged'] == 1;) mysql_query('UPDATE users SET last_seen=NOW() WHERE id='.$user_id);` or something like that.

Comment: OK now this sounds like the solution I'm looking for. I'm not sure if this is the best way but it definitely better than what i currently have. I'm going to play around with it and see if this doesn't solve my issue thanks!

Answer (score 1):

create a statement like this

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])) {
    echo '<p>User is online</p>';
} elseif (!isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])) {
    echo '<p>User Offline!</p>';
} else {
    // another statement if needed to handle errors
}
```

I think this could be adapted to what you need, as long as the cookie is created on the login script.

It may need a little tinkering.

Comment: Okay, but this only works if the user is accessing the page. I'm talking about when user1 is logs in and views the site but leaves. User2 comes along to view user1's page. how do i tell that user1's cookie has timed out or not?

Comment: if the user what, think you hit enter by mistake, I do it to bud :p

Comment: Set the cookie to timeout after so many minutes of non activity, if it happens then the elseif statement will return true, displaying User Offline, if it is set then the user is Online, you could add more else if to display how long or whatever you wanted.

Comment: ok, so maybe I'm not understanding cookies correctly, but the line if(isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])) --- isn't that accessing information on the user's computer? Meaning THAT user would have to be on the page. If so that doesn't help me. Because I'm interested in checking if the user is logged in if ANOTHER user is visiting the page.  To my understanding the code above will only tell me if the user that is visiting the page has the cookie `loggedin` set on their computer.  If that's the case that doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: So change it to a table on your mysql, if user logged in change to 1, set a $_SESSION, if user inactive for 15mins change back to 0, then query the mysql database using the same ifelse structure and there is your answer bud.